# Find the remainder when ${{5^5}^5}^5$ is divided by $24$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

> Find the remainder when ${{5^5}^5}^5$ is divided by $24$

I tried using congruence modulo. $$5^2\equiv1\mod{24}$$
$$5^5=125\mod{24}$$
But this does not give the correct answer.

Comment: @MattSamuel can you give a hint on how to simplify the first congruence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceeding via your method gives:

$$5^2\equiv1\mod{24}$$

$$(5^2)^2\equiv(1)^2\mod{24}$$

$$5\cdot(5^4)\equiv5\cdot(1)\mod{24}$$

$$(5^5)\equiv5\mod{24}$$

So, we have:

$${5^5}^5\equiv{{5}^5}\mod{24}\equiv5 \mod{24}$$

You can continue this as many times as you want. In the end, you'll have a remainder 5.

Answer (score 14):

**Hint**: $5^{5^5}$ is clearly an **odd** number.

Comment: Nice approach! $~~~~$

Comment: Wow, great insight! Much simpler than using formula for Euler's totient function.

Comment: For sure, although the other aproach works in more cases.

Comment: Now that the question is $~1$ hour old, would you mind to develop the hint? (for people like me who didn't get it!)

Comment: @ringø Try simplifying $5^1,5^2,5^3,5^4,5^5$ modulo $24$.  Do you notice anything?

Comment: Ok got it, thank you.

Comment: The hint is $5^{even} = 1 \mod 24$ so $5^{odd}= 5 \mod 24$

Answer (score 7):

To know $a^{b^{c^d}}\bmod 24$ you only need to know $b^{c^d}\bmod \varphi(24)$.

To know $b^{c^d}\bmod \varphi(24)$ you only need to know $c^d\bmod \varphi(\varphi(24))$

---

Lets actually do it:

First note $\varphi(24)=8$, $\varphi(\varphi(24))=4$.

Since $5^5\equiv 1\bmod 4$ we conclude $5^{5^5}\equiv 5^1\bmod 8$.

From here $5^{5^5}\equiv5^1\equiv 5\bmod 8$.

Finally we get $5^{5^{5^5}}\equiv 5^5\bmod 24$

Finally use logarithmic exponentiation:

$5^2\equiv 1,5^4\equiv 1\bmod 24$

therefore $5^5=5\times5^4\equiv 5\times 1\equiv 5 \bmod 24$

Comment: What is $\phi$ here?

Comment: It is euler's totient function.

Answer (score 5):

Using Carmichael function $\lambda(24)=2$

$\implies a^2\equiv1\pmod{24}$ for $(a,24)=1$

Now $a^{2n+1}=a(a^2)^n\equiv a\cdot1^n\pmod{24}\equiv a$

Here $a=5,2n+1=5^{5^5}$

Comment: Nice, using $\lambda$ is like using $\varphi$ but quicker.